# How can I install modules in zf3 without using composer?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

How can we install modules in zend framework 3 manually?.
I mean without using composer how can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a better solution. By editing 3 files we can add a module without using composer.
1.modules.config.php in config folder
  Just add the module name in the return array.
2. autoload_psr4.php in vendor/composer directory
   Add your module information to return array in following format
   'Modulename\' => array($modulepath),
3. autoload_static.php in vendor/composer directory
   Here we have to add the module information in two places
   1. In $prefixLengthsPsr4 array as 
     'M' => array(
            'Modulename\' => 11,
        ),
     The key value indicates the first letter of module name and the numerical 
     value is the length of modulename +1(for /).
   2. In $prefixDirsPsr4 array as
      'modulename\' => 
        array (
            0 => **DIR** . '/../..' . '/module/modulename/src',
        ),
Its done.Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a PSR-4 compatible autoloader (such as Aura Router or so on), which you'd need to include in `public/index.php`.

Then download any modules you want, configure your autoloader, and good luck with your dependencies' dependencies...

---

> May I ask why you would rather not use Composer?
>
> Actually I am gonna use my application with shared hosting which doesn't support shell.

So basically I am not aware of your deployment process, but I'd definitively use composer on my local system, then upload the vendor folder when deploying, however you do that.

If you're using a CI, then do your composer processing there.

Comment: Thanq so much for your reply. Actually I am gonna use my  application with shared hosting which doesn't support shell.So I may need to add modules manually there.

Comment: OK, then never mind my first answer, I'm editing now for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I can't do that because mine is a software product and the requirements may vary depending on different clients and plans.So it is not possible to add modules for each clients.Is there any other ways to add a module without using composer on an already functioning application?

Comment: why not publish with vendor directory?

Comment: The installation and uninstall process is completely automatic in my product so I can't publish vendor directory for each and every user.